# How to clone a copy of all remote branches on local with git

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-checkout, git-remote

I encounter an issue with some of my projetc. I started them on my older computer that doesn't work now. But, I have my projetcs on a gitlab repository. However, when I cloned them on my new computer, I just have master branch on my local, I think it's normal.
So my question is : how can I have the local copy of the content of remote branches on my local please ?

I really don't enjoy to 'checkout' on remote/example branch ... :/
I hope I was clear in my words

Sorry for my English, I'm french.

Have a nice day

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+all+branches

Comment: Thank you so much i didn't see this topic before sorry. However, is it possible to checkout all remote branches to have a clone on local in only one command ?

Answer (score 0):

whenever you clone a repository it always become the master branch and to create a local branch use the command
$ git checkout -b "name of branch"

Comment: Yes thank you but I have already some experience in git and my question isn't how to create a local branch but how to clone remote branches. Thank you